# Tracking branches in bare git repository?

Tags: git, github

Say I have three branches on a central bare Git repository (like GitHub):
-devo
-uat
-prod

prod is what is deployed in public production, uat is an internal copy of production (running next release candidate), and devo has the latest code developers are actively integration testing internally.

I would like to enforce that devo > uat > prod. Meaning that devo is based on uat and uat is based on prod. The idea is to have (mostly) linear history of commits that are promoted from devo->uat->prod, reducing the amount of divergence between the branches (and thus the number of errors making it into production that depended on code that didn't make it to prod).

I can accomplish this with rebase manually, by creating local copies of each branch that track the remote version and being very careful with how I cherry pick (or merge) commits to promote them to the next stage and rebase each branch individually before pushing.

This works, but it is tedious and error prone. I use it for my branches, but introducing a team to use the same system and trusting nobody makes a mistake (especially the ones not super familiar with git) would essentially be impossible.

Is there a way to tell Git I want this kind of tracking, so it can help enforce it with multiple developers all committing to these branches? Can I tell the bare repository on the server that its branches track each other (like I can with local branches in my personal git repo)?

I don't know much about hook scripts, but I could imagine one possibly dealing with the happy case (cherry-picking a commit from devo -> uat and rebasing devo on top of new uat), though then what happens if there's a conflict?

I've searched for similar setups, but can't seem to find the right keywords as "remote tracking branch" really means a local branch tracking a remote one.

Ideas? Thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the time this flow is accomplished by using Jenkins / Hudson or other CI servers… You could tell the developers only to push to `dev`, Jenkins takes that code and on successful test run pushes the code into `uat` and if another job (cucumber or time or other criteria) is met pushes it towards `prod`.

The only problem is I don't know any ways to lock those two branches only Jenkins can push into it. Some Git servers like GitLab provide that functionality to lock branches for push only by privileged accounts.